# jquery makes values inside 'rel' into variables

Tags: jquery, html, variables

I'm currently working on [this](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jqzoom) jquery plugins (an image magnifier) .

I found many of the html will use 'a rel' or relationship for every images that I want to be magnified.

here's the rel example:

```
<a rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: 'images/image1.jpg',largeimage: 'images/image1.jpg'}">
    <img src = images/image1.jpg>
</a>
```

So, I want to change the values of 'smallimage' and 'largeimage'(inside the rel) into variables.

I am not sure if that can be handled by jquery, 
I tried to write some jquery like this:

```
$(function(){
  var src= $("a:first").find('rel').attr();
});
```

but I think that it will store everything inside 'rel' into the variable src

Thank you very much

Comment: the rel attribute contains a string, not an object. You would need to convert that string to an object using $.parseJSON, you can then change the value, turn it back into json with JSON.stringify(theobject), and put it back into the attribute.

Comment: Why aren't you using a data attribute for this rather than rel? *"For anchors containing the href attribute, this attribute(rel) specifies the relationship of the target object to the link object."*

Comment: @KevinB I don't know why they're using rel, I am just following what is written on the index. I'll try that using $.parseJSON, probably will take me a while, be right back

Comment: s/using rel/abusing rel/ :(

Comment: Parsing it as JSON won't work because it's not formatted correctly. A JSON needs to have double quotes, like `'{"gallery": "gal1", "smallimage": "images/image1.jpg","largeimage": "images/image1.jpg"}'`

Comment: I would still like to understand why common/popular image libraries use the rel in the way that the OP was talking about eg. `rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 700, y: 600}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

```
$(function () {
    var src = $.parseJSON($("a:first").prop("rel"));
    src.smallimage = "images/newimage1.jpg";
    src.largeimage = "images/newimage1.jpg";

    alert("Before : " + $("a:first").prop("rel"));
    $("a:first").prop("rel", JSON.stringify(src));
    alert("After : " + $("a:first").prop("rel"));
});
```

And:

```
<a rel='{"gallery": "gal1", "smallimage": "images/image1.jpg","largeimage": "images/image1.jpg"}'>
    <img src = "images/image1.jpg" >
</a>
```

<kbd>**[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EUJdw/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Welcome... Happy to be Helpful... :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should get the `rel` attribute like so:

```
$(element).attr('rel');
```

Second of all, you *could* parse this string as a JSON object, but first you have to make sure that what you have in your `rel` is a **well-formed JSON object**. So, use single quote to wrap the `rel` and double-quotes for the elements, like so:

```
<a rel='{"gallery": "gal1", "smallimage": "images/image1.jpg","largeimage": "images/image1.jpg"}'>
```

Then you can parse the JSON with jQuery and use it as an object, like so:

```
var src= $("a").attr("rel");
src = $.parseJSON(src);
```

You can see a working demo where I used the `src` as an object:

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/opeyax/1/edit)</kbd>

You said you need to use `rel`, but **a better alternative**, though, as suggested in the comments, would be that you use the `data` attributes to store this kind of data, since it's their job, and not the `rel`'s. The `HTML` element would look something like this:

```
<a data-gallery="gal1" data-smallimage="images/small.jpg" data-largeimage="images/large.jpg" href="#">
```

### Edit: how to change the rel object

You asked how to change one of the properties of the `src` object with an `src` attribute of another image tag. You would then do like so:

```
// Get the attribute you want to substitute
var image = $('img').attr('src');

// Substitute it into the object properties
src.smallimage = image;
src.largeimage = image;

// Turn the object back into a string to put it back into the rel attribute
src = JSON.stringify(src);
$('a').attr('rel', src);
```

Comment: is the value src will store everything inside the rel then? what if, say I have another variable named 'image' which store another image's link. And I want to use that variable to change the values of both 'smallimage' and 'largeimage'.

Comment: For example, I have a var image = $("img").attr('src); , and I want to use that variable to change whatever values for 'smallimage' and 'largeimage'

Comment: var src = $(this).attr('src');       $("a:first").prop("rel.smallimage", JSON.stringify(src));          .prop("rel.largeimage", JSON.stringify(src));   Thank you @Sunyatasattva I've found what I wanted to know.

Comment: Uhm, just modified the answer to meet your new requirement.